# Using System.Logger and Log4j2 inside Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, logging, eclipse-rcp, log4j2

I am developing an RCP application, and I want to use the System.Logger feature (I'm using Java 21) to abstract logger, and use *log4j2* as logger implementation.

I am developing an RCP application and want to use the `System.Logger`. I use the logger feature (Java 21) to abstract the logger and use *log4j2* as the logger implementation.

I have several plugins and one of them is used as a "library" plugin: it gathers dependencies from maven (external and local projects) and exports all packages from the different jar files so that libraries are available for all plugins with a dependency to lib plugin.

I use `System.Logger` in some libraries to log messages, so the library is not dependent on a specific logger implementation (the library's caller makes an implementation choice).

I want to configure a plugin to load the *log4j-jpl* service so that each call to `System.Logger` uses log4j instead of the default JUL (if possible).

For now, in my plugins' code, I'm using *log4j* directly and a custom configuration file to log to the console & file, and it's working fine.
But when the plugin calls a method from a library using `System.Logger`, the default *JUL logger* is used, not *log4j*.
I also tried to use `System.Logger` directly in the plugin, and the result is the same: *log4j-jpl* doesn't seem to be seen by the RCP app.

It works fine when using the same library in a Java project (not RCP) with *log4j-jpl*. So, I guess the problem comes with the context and exposed services of the RCP bundles.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make the *log4j-jpl* service available to all plugins (and libs) when the RCP app is launched? I couldn't find much documentation on that topic.

Comment: Did you happen to read the documentation of [System.LoggerFinder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.LoggerFinder.html#getLogger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module))?  You can write your own LoggerFinder implementation which returns a System.Logger that delegates to Log4J.

Comment: Isn't that the job of log4j-jpl lib (implementing a LoggerFinder) ? If yes the point here is to make it available for all bundles at RCP startup so that the implementation is used by all plugins. That's where I have troubles making it work

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that it is supposed to be doing that.  By any chance are you making a “fat jar”?  That might cause the log4j-jpl service descriptor and module descriptor to be dropped.

Comment: For now I'm trying to make it work inside Eclipse environment, not even with the RCP packaged standalone app. So the _jpl_ jar is not modified and still has (normally) its descriptor and service descriptor present. I think my issue is having RCP bundles sharing the _jpl_ service. As I said in classic java app context it works easily, but in RCP context not so much.